# How to avoid entering negative values in kendo numeric text box?

Tags: html, kendo-ui

How to avoid entering negative values in kendo numeric text box? By giving "Min:0" it doesnt allow to enter negative values but by moving arrow up and down it allows negative values. Please suggest me how to avoid this?

Answer (score 6):

Following the Web Demos from [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/numerictextbox/index.html), it is perfectly functioning to only set **min** to 0.

Note: The settings in kendoUI are **case sensitive**. **Min:0** will not work, you'd have to set **min:0**

Code:

```
$("#ntb").kendoNumericTextBox({
    min: 0
});
```

Demo:

[Click Me - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xJ8Xd/)